# calling C functions in java

Tags: java, c, web-services, api

I have a tool kit which is written in C. I want to make a java web service which will use this toolkit. how can I do that. how can I call the functions of this toolkit

Comment: Look into JNA. It makes things pretty easy.

Comment: You should really try to research before asking...

Answer (score 0):

If the toolkit gives outputs, can you just take the outputs and pipe them?

If not, I think it'd just be easier to convert it yourself, unless pointers are involved.

Otherwise,

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html#769